# jQuery if statement problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to change image in the div if the user click on any span,if div already contains roz variable(which comes from the index page) then by clickng on the span, img roz should not be appneded but it does not work.

i am not sure if the first part of IF statement in jQuery is right

here is html part

```
<div class="iconWrapper">
<ul class="color">
<li><a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color1"></span></a> </li>
<li><a href="#" title="Selecteer "><span class="color2" ></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color3"></span></a> </l>
<li><a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color4"></span></a></li>
</ul> </div>

<div id="div1" > <?php if(isset($_SESSION['img'])){
echo '<img src="' . $_SESSION['img'] . '" >' ; }
?>
<form method="post" action="weekDays.php">
<input name="kleur" type="text" value="" id="hiddencolor" />

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var roz='../../photo/roz1.jpg';

    $('.iconWrapper span').click(function(e){
        var kleur=$(this).attr('class');
    if($('#div1').attr('src' == roz)){
        $('#div1' ).children('img').remove() ;
        $('#div1'). append('<img src="img/300.jpg" />');
    }else{
       $('#div1').children('img').remove();
       $('#div1').append('<img src="img/106.jpg" />');
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert(  $('#div1').html()  );       
});
```

});

Comment: What's your `kleur` variable for? You don't actually use it! Also, is `#div1` actually an image tag? Because you've made it look like a div.

Comment: If you store the reference to `$('#div1')`. It will be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you actually want this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.iconWrapper span').click(function(e) {
        $('#div1').find('img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
            return src == '../../photo/roz1.jpg' ? 'img/300.jpg' : 'img/106.jpg';
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Given that your current code seems to be looking for a `src` attribute on what I presume is a `div`.

Comment: @Juhana: More specifically, it's **the** [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 6):

```
if($('#div1').attr('src' == roz))
```

should be

```
if($('#div1').attr('src') == roz)
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is being used incorrectly. You need to use `attr('src')` to *get* the 'src' attribute and then compare it to your `roz` value.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    var roz = '../../photo/roz1.jpg';
    $('.iconWrapper span').click(function(e) {
        var kleur = $(this).attr('class');
        if ($('#div1').attr('src') == roz) {
            $('#div1').children('img').remove();
            $('#div1').append('<img src="img/300.jpg" />');
        } else {
            $('#div1').children('img').remove();
            $('#div1').append('<img src="img/106.jpg" />');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($('#div1').html());
    });
});
```